# Can we create windows service with C# Socket

Tags: c#, windows, sockets, windows-services

I want to create a windows service from this code. Anyone can help for creating a windows service. I tried many time myself but i get success 50%. In my code i had 3 function that i want to perform after connecting with client application.

```
    public static class Program
    {
        public static TcpClient client;
        private static TcpListener listener;
        private static string ipString;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IPAddress[] localIp = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress address in localIp)
            {
                if (address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    ipString = address.ToString();
                }
            }
            IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipString), 1234);
            listener = new TcpListener(ep);
            listener.Start();
            client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            while (client.Connected)
            {
                try
                {
                    const int bytesize = 1024 * 1024;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesize];
                    string x = client.GetStream().Read(buffer, 0, bytesize).ToString();
                    var data = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer);

                    if (data.ToUpper().Contains("SLP2"))
                    {
                        Sleep();
                    }
                    else if (data.ToUpper().Contains("SHTD3"))
                    {
                        Shutdown();
                    }
                    else if (data.ToUpper().Contains("TSC1"))
                    {
                        var bitmap = SaveScreenshot();
                        var stream = new MemoryStream();
                        bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
                        sendData(stream.ToArray(), client.GetStream());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {
                    client.Dispose();
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this might help: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-windows-service-in-net-with-topshelf/

Comment: `x` tells you **how many bytes** of `buffer` now contain actual network data. You just ignore that though and convert the entire buffer into a string. There's *no* guarantee that what you've received represents "one" `Write` from the other end - TCP is a stream of bytes, not messaging.